# Matplotlib not plotting logscale properly when using stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I have 5 lists you can see below

```
always_failing_list_tt = [0.221,0.221,0.221, 0.221]
always_passing_list_tt = [0.335,0.335,0.335, 0.335]
all_test_tt = [108.281]
keep_list_tt = [93.104,85.011,76.111,70.932]
eppm_plot = [0,35482,70517,101074]
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart so that the second bar I plot compared to `all_test_tt` is a combination of (`always_passing_list_tt` + `always_failing_list_tt` + `keep_list_tt`)

I do that using the code below:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
x = np.arange(len(eppm_plot)) 
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (25,5))

rects1 = ax1.bar(x - width/2, all_test_tt, width, label='full_block_coverage_tt', color = 'y')
rects4 = ax1.bar(x+ width/2, keep_list_tt, width,bottom =list(np.add(always_failing_list_tt,always_passing_list_tt)) ,label = 'lean_coverage_tt', color='#fbb4ae', edgecolor='#fbb4ae')
rects2 = ax1.bar(x+ width/2, always_failing_list_tt ,width,label = 'always_failing_list', color='#b3cde3', edgecolor='#b3cde3')
rects3 = ax1.bar(x + width/2, always_passing_list_tt,width,bottom = always_failing_list_tt, label = 'always_passing_list',color='#ccebc5', edgecolor='#ccebc5')

ax1.set_ylabel('Test time in seconds')
ax1.set_xlabel('EPPM in e6')
ax1.set_title('Full, Lean coverage TT vs EPPM for ATPG,FUNC and MBIST blocks combined')
ax1.set_xticks(x)
ax1.set_xticklabels(eppm_plot)
ax1.legend()
ax1.bar_label(rects1)
ax1.bar_label(rects4)
ax1.bar_label(rects2, padding =-3)
ax1.bar_label(rects3, padding = 12)
ax1.set_yscale("log")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plotting without logscale]

plotting without log scale

[image: plotting with log scale]

plotting with log scale

As you can see the `always_failing_list_tt` is not getting show even in log scale even though time is being reported. Could anybody tell me what the issue is? Would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code work fine. In both cases the bars are plotted correctly, however they are either too small with respect to other bars, or they are outside the plot area.

**Without log scale**

Zooming in the bottom part of the plot: `ax1.set_ylim(0, 1)`:

[image]

Without zooming you are not able to see it because they are too small compared to other bars.

**With log scale**

Zooming in the bottom part of the plot: `ax1.set_ylim(1e-1, 1.5e2)`:

[image]

Without zooming you are not able to see it because the auto-resizing of the y axis cuts the bottom blue bar out of the plot.

---

Be cautious using log scale: you bars start from `0`, this means in log scale they lengthen, starting from `-∞`. So in log scale there is not a defined value from which to start your plot: you could choose arbitrarily to start from `1e-1`, `1e-2`, `1e-3` and so on. Whatever value you choose, will affect the plot aspect and the relative proportions of the bars heights:

`ax1.set_ylim(1e-5, 1.5e2)`
[image]

Comment: awesome thanks for the info, so i need to use ylimit to clean it up

Comment: yup, upvoted it and accepted the answer, thanks @zephyr